# Javascript CSS rotation inaccuracy

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

I've been making a little analog clock icon via CSS and Javascript and have run into a strange graphical glitch.

```js
function r() {
  var vwMin, r;
  if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
    vwMin = window.innerWidth;
  } else {
    vwMin = window.innerHeight;
  }
  r = vwMin * .0225 - 1;
  if (r < 0) {
    r += 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("min").style.transformOrigin = "50% calc(100% - " + r + "px)";
  document.getElementById("min").style.bottom = "calc(50% - " + r + "px)";
  document.getElementById("hr").style.transformOrigin = "50% calc(100% - " + r + "px)";
  document.getElementById("hr").style.bottom = "calc(50% - " + r + "px)";
}

function clock() {
  r();
  var date = new Date(),
      hours;
  if (date.getHours() > 12) {
    hours = ((date.getHours() - 12) / 12) + (date.getMinutes() / 720);
  } else {
    hours = (date.getHours() / 12) + (date.getMinutes() / 720);
  }
  var mins = date.getMinutes() / 60;
  var hours = .5;
  var mins = 0;
  document.querySelector('#hr').style.transform = 'rotate(' + hours + 'turn)';
  document.querySelector('#min').style.transform = 'rotate(' + mins + 'turn)';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  clock();
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    r();
  };
});
```

```css
#clock {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  width: 70vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 6vmin;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#clock>* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2.25vmin;
  border: 2.25vmin solid;
  border-radius: 2.25vmin;
  background: black;
}

#min {
  height: 25vmin;
}

#hr {
  height: 16vmin;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock">
  <div id="hr"></div>
  <div id="min"></div>
</div>
```

The script finds the location of wherr to transform-origin and offset the div such that the clock hands intersect cleanly at all times. However, the CSS rotation does not seem to be rotating at the exact horizontal center of the div. For example, if I manually set the clock to 6:00, the minute hand will be clean while the rotated hour hand will be blurred.

What is going on, and how would I fix this (if possible)?

Comment: Can you put the manual time into the snippet so we can see the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I put in the manual time into the snippet. Interestingly enough, the snippet shows the non-rotated minute hand to be blurry, but you can still see how there is a slight disjoint at the center of the clock by the hands caused by the rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up coming up with is a rework using SVG instead of using divs. What I think was happening was that since the center of the hand divs were almost always on a subpixel, most browsers would alias or round to the nearest pixel thus causing the clock hands to be disjunct if rotated. SVG allows one to draw from a distinct origin which solved the issue. Here is the code used that solved this:

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="analog-clock">
      <svg width="100vmin" height="100vmin" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
        <circle id="clock-face" cx="0" cy="0" r="45"/>
        <line id="h-hand" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-22"/>
        <line id="m-hand" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-33"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.analog-clock{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#clock-face{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 6;
  fill: white;
}
#h-hand, #m-hand{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 4.5;
}
```

JS

```
function clock() {
  var d = new Date();
  function setAttr(id,deg) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + ', 0, 0)');
  };
  setAttr('h-hand', 30 * ((d.getHours() % 12) + d.getMinutes() / 60));
  setAttr('m-hand', 6 * d.getMinutes());
}

window.onload = clock();
setInterval(function() {
  clock();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforms can act very weird with subpixel movements, even when there shouldn't be any. You can usually fix this by setting `translateZ(0)` and it looks like it works in your case. Since you're modifying an inline `transform` already, just add the Z to it like so:

```
 document.querySelector('#hr').style.transform = 'rotate(' + hours + 'turn) translateZ(0)';
 document.querySelector('#min').style.transform = 'rotate(' + mins + 'turn) translateZ(0)';
```

## Edit:

Funny enough it seems like this actually makes the hour hand blurry *sometimes* based on the screensize - worked fine in my full screen Snippet but is a tad blurry in the tiny snippet box

```js
function r() {
  var vwMin, r;
  if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
    vwMin = window.innerWidth;
  } else {
    vwMin = window.innerHeight;
  }
  r = vwMin * .0225 - 1;
  if (r < 0) {
    r += 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("min").style.transformOrigin = "50% calc(100% - " + r + "px)";
  document.getElementById("min").style.bottom = "calc(50% - " + r + "px)";
  document.getElementById("hr").style.transformOrigin = "50% calc(100% - " + r + "px)";
  document.getElementById("hr").style.bottom = "calc(50% - " + r + "px)";
}

function clock() {
  r();
  var date = new Date(),
    hours;
  if (date.getHours() > 12) {
    hours = ((date.getHours() - 12) / 12) + (date.getMinutes() / 720);
  } else {
    hours = (date.getHours() / 12) + (date.getMinutes() / 720);
  }
  var mins = date.getMinutes() / 60;
  
  hours = 6;
  mins = 0;
  document.querySelector('#hr').style.transform = 'rotate(' + hours + 'turn)';
  document.querySelector('#min').style.transform = 'rotate(' + mins + 'turn) translateZ(0)';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  clock();
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    r();
  };
});
```

```css
#clock {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  width: 70vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 6vmin;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#clock>* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2.25vmin solid;
  border-radius: 2.25vmin;
  background: black;
}

#min {
  height: 25vmin;
}

#hr {
  height: 16vmin;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock">
  <div id="hr"></div>
  <div id="min"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and found in some cases performance in the hands increased, but in some cases was worse. I messed around with converting from turns to degrees and that seems to have helped for whatever reason.